# how to complete CloudKit save on app quit

Tags: cloudkit

I have an app which saves some state data with CloudKit. The save and restore work properly however, I want to save the last state when the user selects the Quit command. I issue the call;

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
   {

```
    cmsHW.saveState()
```

}

but the CloudKit save called in saveState() never completes. Is there a way to wait for it to finish before the app exits?

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this was to;

1 - call the saveState function in applicationShouldTerminate

```
      func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender : NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply
      {

          cmsHW.saveState(sender:self)
          return  NSApplication.TerminateReply.terminateLater
      }
```

and
2 - when the store ops are finished;

```
        NSApp.reply(toApplicationShouldTerminate: true)
```

to complete the termination.